# How to enable or disable button according to value of the variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I use pure javascript.
I have this row in my asp page:

```
<input type="button" value="..." id="ffcolorswtach" style="width: 20px; height: 19px; position: relative; left: 15px; top: 0px; color: #ff0000; background-color: #d8d5d5;" onclick="PickColor(1, false, false)" role="button" />
```

Also I have javascript variable in my client page that contains true/false values:

```
var isColorSelected
```

When isColorSelected is false i want to enable input element above if false I want to disable it.Any idea how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following:

```
    if(isColorSelected != true)
      document.getElementById("ffcolorswtach").disabled = true;
    else
      document.getElementById("ffcolorswtach").disabled = false;
```

This is finding that element within the DOM and using the built in browser capability to disable the element for you.

Comment: Could you please add some commentary to your answer to explain what the code is doing / help elaborate why this is a good solution for the problem at hand.

Comment: @lan-Hey I have added the explaination. This is the simplest solution I could think of :)

Comment: Thanks - I've edited it slightly to put some commentary outside of the code snippet. It's less likely to get picked up as being a poor answer and sitting in the review queue (which is where I came across it).

Answer (score 0):

In general you want the [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-disabled) property.:

```
document.getElementById("ffcolorswtach").disabled = true;
```

You can set that to `true` / `false` at the same time your variable changes.

Answer (score 0):

HTML DOM disabled Property -  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_disabled.asp

```js
var isColorSelected = true;
document.getElementById("ffcolorswtach").disabled = isColorSelected;
```

```html
<input type="button" value="..." id="ffcolorswtach" style="width: 20px; height: 19px; position: relative; left: 15px; top: 0px; color: #ff0000; background-color: #d8d5d5;" onclick="PickColor(1, false, false)" role="button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery

```
if(isColorSelected==true)
  $('#ffcolorswtach').prop('disabled', false);
else
  $('#ffcolorswtach').prop('disabled', true);
```